# What is $T^0_0(M,W)$ where $W$ is trivial vector bundle over a compact manifold $M$?

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds

Let $W=(M \times \mathbb{R}, pr, M)$ be the trivial vector bundle over a compact manifold $M$, and define $$V=T^0_0(M,W) := T^0_0M \otimes W,$$
and $V$ is called "the vector bundle of $W$-valued (0,0)-tensors on $M$".

Apparently we can identify $T^0_0(M,W) = T^0_0(M, \mathbb{R}) = T^0_0(M)$.

My question is, is there a simple way to describe $V$? Is it $V=\mathbb{R}$?

Here, $T^i_k M$ is the $(i,k)$-tensor bundle.

Comment: You define $T^i_kM$ as a tensor bundle over a manifold. But in your question, you use $T^i_k(M,W)$ (or more specifically $T^0_0(M,W).$ What's the definition of that?

Comment: @jflipp It is defined as the RHS of the first displayed equation, i.e., the tensor product of $T^0_0M$ with $W$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not very common to use the language "$(0,0)$-tensor", but by convention a $(0,0)$-tensor on a vector space $V$ is just a scalar, and so a $(0,0)$ tensor field on a manifold $M$ -- that is, an section of $T_0^0(M)$ -- is a smooth function on $M$.

Likewise, it's obvious that the smooth functions on $M$ are exactly the sections of the trivial bundle $W = M \times \mathbb{R}$. Thus $T_0^0(M) \cong W$ as bundles, and both are trivial one-dimensional bundles.

It follows from the definitions that if I take the tensor product of two one-dimensional trivial bundles over $M$, what I get is a one-dimensional trivial bundle. 
So, $V \cong W \cong T_0^0(M)$ is the trivial rank one bundle over $M$, whose sections are the smooth functions on $M$.

Comment: hey thanks for explaining. Can you explain one more thing: if $V$ is as in the OP, if I see something like $L^1_{loc}(V)$, should I interpret that as $L^1_{loc}(M)$, the set of locally integrable functions over $M$?

Comment: That's *likely* to be what that means, since morally if $E$ is a vector bundle, $L^1_{loc}(E)$ ought to be a space of sections of that bundle (the locally integrable ones). (But someday someone somewhere is going to want to talk about locally integrable functions on the total space of $E$, and I suppose they'll need a notation for that, and who knows what they'll choose, and it might be $L^1_{loc}(E)$... so make sure the first interpretation makes sense in context.)